# Swift 3: DispatchQueue Timing over URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I'm attempting to create a progress indicator for uploading images to my server! My goal is to have a `UIView` that contains the `UIProgressView` and `UILabel` display the current status of the photos that are being uploaded.

Every time that my code sends off an image to my server, it should loop to the next picture while updating the `UILabel` (referenced `lblImagesRemaining`) and the `UIProgressView` (referenced `progressImages`).

I was able to get the `UIView` (given the reference `viewUploadBox`) to appear and somewhat update the progress, but I can't seem to get it to *completely* work. The `viewUploadBox` will appear, but neither the `lblImagesRemaining` nor the `progressImages` will update until the upload process is ~70% done. Although, once it does hit that ~70% completetion, it will there on out update with every time an image is sent off.

Here's my `UIViewController` before the `Upload Test` button is triggered:
[image]

Here's my `UIViewController` once the `Upload Test` button is first triggered:
[image]

Here's my `UIViewController` once the upload process is ~70% done:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func uploadTest(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageCount = collectImages() // Collect images also prepares the tests with dictionaries for images to upload.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.viewUploadBox.isHidden = false
            self.lblImagesRemaining.text = "Images Remaining: " + String(imageCount)
            self.view.alpha = 0.5
            self.viewUploadBox.alpha = 1.5
        }
        let time = DispatchTime.now() + 0.01
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) { // The asyncAfter was used to ensure that the viewUploadBox appeared.
            self.uploadTest(imageCount: imageCount)
        }
    }


func uploadTest(imageCount: Int) {
        let progressFactor = 1.0 / Double(imageCount)
        var i = 1
        var imagesRemaining = imageCount
        while i < 8 {
            let imageDictionary = projectHandler.testHandler.getImageDictionary(i)
            let test = imageDictionary["test"] as! String
            for (key, value) in imageDictionary {
                if key == "test" || key == "count" {
                    continue
                }
                let url = NSURL(string: "http://IMAGEUPLOADLOCATION.PHP")
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
                //define the multipart request type
                request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((value as! UIImage), 0.2)
                let body = NSMutableData()
                let constructedName = userdata.valueForKey("name_full") + "(ID-" + userdata.valueForKey("id_ACCOUNT") + ")"
                let parameters = [
                    "name" : constructedName,
                    "project" : projectHandler.projectName,
                    "picturefile" : key + ".jpeg",
                    "testname" : test,
                    "projectid" : projectHandler.idPROJECT,
                    "accountid" : userdata.valueForKey("id_ACCOUNT"),
                    "brazerid" : projectHandler.idBrazer]
                //define the data post parameter
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                    body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                }
                let fname = "image"
                let mimetype = "image/jpeg"
                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname); \"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append(image_data!)
                body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                request.httpBody = body as Data
                let session = URLSession.shared
                session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                    (data, response, error) in
                    if(error != nil){
                        print("error")
                    } else {
                            do {
                            let dataString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                            print("Response: \(response!)")
                            print("Data: \(data!)")
                            print(dataString)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.progressImages.progress += Float(progressFactor)
                        imagesRemaining -= 1
                        self.lblImagesRemaining.text = "Images Remaining: " + String(imagesRemaining)
                        if imagesRemaining == 0 {
                            self.viewUploadBox.isHidden = true
                            self.btnEmail.isEnabled = true
                            self.view.alpha = 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
            i += 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a lot of confusing code here. You pass `imageCount` to your `uploadTest` method. But you have a `while` loop hardcoded to iterate 7 times. Why? Then you have a loop that iterates the keys and values of `imageDictionary`. You start a new `URLSession` for each key/value pair. Why?

Comment: There are 7 `Test` objects, which are a custom designed classes. The `collectImages` method at the beginning of the `uploadTest` code will create the 7 different dictionaries and tell the `imageCount` how many images will need to be uploaded. The `getImageDictionairy(i)` method is used to cycle through the 7 dictionaries. There will always be 7 dictionaries to cycle through, so it is hardcoded with a `while` loop. As for the new `URLSession`s, it may come down to coding ignorance. I do not know a more proper way to upload 76 images with different key/value pairs without multiple `URLSession`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like a race condition. try next snippet.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Dispatch
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let q = DispatchQueue(label: "test") // serial queue

var j = 0

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) {  i in
    q.async {
        j += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(i, j)
        }
    }
}

print("total",j)
```

Check the code, try to imagine what the code will print out and compare the result with your expectation :-)

it prints

```
total 6
0 10
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 10
7 10
8 10
9 10
```

is this what did you expect?

Let's try something more advanced :-)

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Dispatch
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let q = DispatchQueue(label: "test") // serial queue

class S {
    let q = DispatchQueue(label: "sync", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var v: Int = 0
    func add(i: Int) {
        q.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.v += i
        }
    }
    var i: Int {
        get {
            return q.sync {
                return v
            }
        }
    }
}

let s = S()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) {  i in
    q.async {
        s.add(i: 1)
        let k = s.i
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(i, s.i, k)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks much better, but check the result again.

```
0 4 1
1 4 2
2 4 3
3 4 4
4 6 5
5 6 6
6 8 7
7 8 8
8 10 9
9 10 10
```

See the difference between values in second and third 'column'. The second looks like your progress bar, the third is what do you want.

Hm, but we use serial queue dispatched from concurrent ... let's remove it

```
import Dispatch
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


class S {
    let q = DispatchQueue(label: "sync", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var v: Int = 0
    func add(i: Int) {
        q.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.v += i
        }
    }
    var i: Int {
        get {
            return q.sync {
                return v
            }
        }
    }
}

let s = S()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) {  i in
        s.add(i: 1)
        let k = s.i
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(i, s.i, k)
        }
}
```

and we are at the beginning again .....

```
1 10 4
0 10 4
3 10 4
2 10 5
5 10 7
4 10 7
6 10 7
7 10 10
8 10 10
9 10 10
```

**Solution**

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Dispatch
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class S {
    let q = DispatchQueue(label: "sync", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var v: Int = 0
    func add(i: Int) {
        q.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.v += i
            let k = self.v
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("update progress", k)
            }
        }
    }
    var i: Int {
        get {
            return q.sync {
                return v
            }
        }
    }
}

let s = S()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) {  i in
    s.add(i: 1)
    print(i, s.i)
}
```

prints

```
0 3
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 7
5 9
8 9
7 9
6 9
9 10
update progress 1
update progress 2
update progress 3
update progress 4
update progress 5
update progress 6
update progress 7
update progress 8
update progress 9
update progress 10
```

There is no guarantee in which order the concurrent tasks finished, but our progress is properly indicated.